# What can be done to optimize the following Oracle SQL view?

Tags: sql, oracle

We will implement an Oracle SQL view table and currently, it uses excessive count (*) to be left join on another table:

```
  SELECT
        portfolio.id as id, 
        portfolio.name as name, 
        portfolio.number as number, 
        currency.id as currencyId,
        currency.key as currencyIso, 
        customer.id as cbsId,
        (CASE WHEN position_tbl.max_available_balance >0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as hasAvailableBalance,
        (CASE WHEN wallet_tbl.wallet_count > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as hasWallet, 
        (CASE WHEN account_tbl.fiat_account_count > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as hasFiatAccount,
        wallet_tbl.wallet_count,
        account_tbl.fiat_account_count
    FROM SCHEMA.CUSTOMER customer
    INNER JOIN SCHEMA.PORTFOLIO portfolio on portfolio.customer_id = customer.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as wallet_count, 
            portfolio_number 
        FROM SCHEMA.WALLET 
        GROUP BY portfolio_number) wallet_tbl on wallet_tbl.portfolio_number= portfolio.portfolio_number
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(position.available_balance) as max_available_balance, 
            portfolio_number 
        FROM SCHEMA.POSITION position
        GROUP BY position.portfolio_number) position_tbl on position_tbl.portfolio_number =portfolio.portfolio_number
    INNER JOIN CURRENCY currency on currency.id = portfolio.reference_currency_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as fiat_account_count, 
            portfolio_id 
        FROM ACCOUNT 
        GROUP BY portfolio_id) account_tbl on account_tbl.portfolio_id = portfolio.id
```

Can someone suggest or advice what can be optimized here for performance?

Comment: Please provide an actual query plan and actual rowcounts for each joined table. See [query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) tag info for details

Comment: it uses excessive count (*) to be left join on another table: - ??what do you mean

Comment: LEFT JOIN `LATERAL` derived tables?

Comment: Will it help to use `count(col)` instead of `count(*)`, where col is a not null column? (I'm asking because I'm not sure if the database automatically does this in its algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IF* this is a standalone query or if it's queried as a view *without adding any additional predicates* (which means there's no reason for this to be a "view" at all), then it's probably merging the inline views and postponing the GROUP BYs until after the join, which causes temporary many-to-many joins. It could also be bad stats driving nested loops inappropriately.

If this is the case then, 1) *Gather stats on all the tables involved*. If that doesn't fix it, *try these hints* (in four places) and see how it does:

```
 SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(customer portfolio wallet_tbl currency account_tbl currency) PARALLEL(16) */
        portfolio.id as id, 
        portfolio.name as name, 
        portfolio.number as number, 
        currency.id as currencyId,
        currency.key as currencyIso, 
        customer.id as cbsId,
        (CASE WHEN position_tbl.max_available_balance >0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as hasAvailableBalance,
        (CASE WHEN wallet_tbl.wallet_count > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as hasWallet, 
        (CASE WHEN account_tbl.fiat_account_count > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as hasFiatAccount,
        wallet_tbl.wallet_count,
        account_tbl.fiat_account_count
    FROM SCHEMA.CUSTOMER customer
    INNER JOIN SCHEMA.PORTFOLIO portfolio on portfolio.customer_id = customer.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ COUNT(*) as wallet_count, 
            portfolio_number 
        FROM SCHEMA.WALLET 
        GROUP BY portfolio_number) wallet_tbl on wallet_tbl.portfolio_number= portfolio.portfolio_number
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ MAX(position.available_balance) as max_available_balance, 
            portfolio_number 
        FROM SCHEMA.POSITION position
        GROUP BY position.portfolio_number) position_tbl on position_tbl.portfolio_number =portfolio.portfolio_number
    INNER JOIN CURRENCY currency on currency.id = portfolio.reference_currency_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ COUNT(*) as fiat_account_count, 
            portfolio_id 
        FROM ACCOUNT 
        GROUP BY portfolio_id) account_tbl on account_tbl.portfolio_id = portfolio.id
```

*IF*, however, this is a real view which you are querying with additional predicates, then the above likely does not apply, and you haven't given us the actual SQL that you're trying to tune. When you query a view, the program the database executes includes not just the view content but the SQL calling the view, and that can change everything. For example, if you compile the above as a view and then use it to query a particular customer or portfolio, the hints I suggested above will be absolutely wrong, for that changes what data you are going after from 100% of those tables to only a small slice, which changes the optimal execution plan. If this is what's happening, you'll have to ensure proper indexing on all the join columns and predicate columns and maintain current statistics, as hinting a view used by various different queries is rarely successful due to how those invoking queries change what needs to happen. For this reason I generally advise developers to minimize their use of views.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to respond to my question. I am querying with additional predicates. The predicates will be the following:

`where hasAvailableBalance = :hasAvailableBalance
id in (:ids)
hasWallet = :hasWallet
hasFiatAccount = :hasFiatAccount`

Comment: @Java2Avaj, In that case, particularly because of the "`id in (:ids)`" predicate, ignore my hint suggestions, they will be wrong in this case. You will need to index `portfolio.id`, `customer.id`, `account.portfolio_id` and *maybe* (if they are large) `wallet.portfolio_number`, `position.portfolio_number` and `currency.id`.